# How to make the font size become smaller with division nesting?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `<div` nesting as following

```
<div>Main Issue
      <div>Level1
             <div>Sublevel</div>
             <div>Another sublevel</div>
      </div>
      <div>Level2
             <div>Second sublevel</div>
      </div>
</div>
```

I need a `js` function that would make a `ONE TIME UPDATE` such that all sub-level elements have smaller fonts, but all siblings have the same font size.

The reason I am not using the `css : div < div` is because I might append other elements to the divisions, so I need the font sizes to be applied only to the above skeleton

---

This is what I tried . But it makes ALL consequent div elements smaller

```
var ic = 0; 
var fontSize = 1;
    var test = function(parent) { 
        var children = nodes[parent]; 
        fontSize = 1; 
        fontSize = fontSize == 4 ? 4 : fontSize+1;
        div.append("<h"+fontSize+">" + parent + "</h"+fontSize+">");  
        } 

        for (ic in children) {
            var child = children[ic]; 
            div.append(test(child)); 
            if (ic == children.length - 1) {
            fontSize = 1;  
            } 
        }
        return div; 
    }
```

Comment: @SleekGeek is right. You need to show us what you have tried (and possibly why it didn't work). Why can't you use CSS classes?

Comment: @Sleek Geek I pasted my current attempt. But it's making all elements smaller, but I need siblings to be the same size

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recurse through the DOM and adjust each level by -2px starting at 16px. Alternatively, you could replace the decreasing levels with an object which correlated to depth and font size. Further, this will hit every element in the document, you may wish to change the iteration to start somewhere other than at document.body.

```js
(function fonts(parent,depth){
 for(var i = 0; i < parent.children.length; i++){
  var child = parent.children[i];
  child.style.fontSize = (16-2*depth)+"px";
  if(child.firstChild != null ) fonts(child,depth+1);
 }
})(document.body,0)
```

```html
<div>Main Issue
      <div>Level1
             <div>Sublevel</div>
             <div>Another sublevel</div>
      </div>
      <div>Level2
             <div>Second sublevel</div>
      </div>
</div>
```